# App de división de dinero. Problema con manipulación de objetos

Tags: javascript, poo, javascript-objeto

Estoy con un problema para hacer mi app. Soy nuevo en programación web y quería hacer una pagina para dividir gastos entre amigos. Lo que yo quería hacer era una serie de inputs en el front end para que el que lo use pueda ingresar los diferentes gastos y las personas que participaron de esos gastos, completando así un objeto que quedaría así:

```
var eventDivider = {
  carne: {
    monto: 100,
    participantes: ["Lucas","Pablo","Franco"]
    },
  bebida: {
    monto: 50,
    participantes: ["Pablo","Franco"]
    }
}
```

Lo segundo sería realizar una función que divida el monto de los participantes y aquí está mi duda
¿Cómo accedo a los keys? Porque tengo que hacer una función que funciona sea cual sea el nombre de los keys, que en el ejemplo de arriba le puse "carne" y "bebida" pero podría tener cualquier otro.

Yo realicé el siguiente código pero me dice que no se puede leer 'monto'

```js
function division (amountTotal, persons){
  var amountPerson = 0
  amountPerson = amountTotal / persons
  console.log( amountPerson)
}

var eventDivider = {
  carne: {
    monto: 100,
    participantes: ["Lucas","Pablo","Franco"]
    },
  bebida: {
    monto: 50,
    participantes: ["Pablo","Franco"]
    },
  cantOp:['carne', 'bebida']
}

for(let i=0; i < eventDivider.cantOp.length; i++){
  var nameEvent = eventDivider.cantOp[i]
  division(eventDivider.nameEvent.monto,eventDivider.nameEvent.participantes.length)
  
}
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias a todos por ayudar <3

Comment: Podrías publicar el código como texto por favor !!

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes, y mucho menos se puede hacer _copypaste_ de tu código tal como está. Lee [ask].

Comment: Ahi lo puse como texto! gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí estás accediendo mal a tu objeto:

```js
division(eventDivider.nameEvent.monto, eventDivider.nameEvent.participantes.length)
```

Debería ser:

```js
division(eventDivider[nameEvent].monto, eventDivider[nameEvent].participantes.length)
```

Ya que `nameEvent` es una variable que contiene el nombre de una de las propiedades (que son `carne` o `bebida`) de tu objeto `eventDivider`. Entonces, al utilizar los corchetes, decimos que podemos acceder a la propiedad que le corresponde utilizando el valor de la variable `nameEvent`.

Y pues, al escribir `eventDivider.nameEvent`, indicas que tratas de acceder a una propiedad llamada `nameEvent` del objeto `eventDivider`, la cual no existe!, y lo que hacías es tratar de leer el valor de `monto` de `nameEvent`, pero como `nameEvent` no existe, tienes ese error.

---

Código:

```js
function division(amountTotal, persons) {
  var amountPerson = 0
  amountPerson = amountTotal / persons
  console.log(amountPerson)
}

var eventDivider = {
  carne: {
    monto: 100,
    participantes: ["Lucas", "Pablo", "Franco"]
  },
  bebida: {
    monto: 50,
    participantes: ["Pablo", "Franco"]
  },
  cantOp: ['carne', 'bebida']
}

for (let i = 0; i < eventDivider.cantOp.length; i++) {
  var nameEvent = eventDivider.cantOp[i]
  division(eventDivider[nameEvent].monto, eventDivider[nameEvent].participantes.length)
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!